# Mysql - select table1.something, table2.* WHERE replace all columns like %something%

Tags: mysql

I have following query:

```
SELECT `mmetal`.`id`, `mmetal`.`name`, `steelmarks`.`EN`, `steelmarks`.`DIN` FROM `mmetal` LEFT JOIN `steelmarks` ON `mmetal`.`id`=`steelmarks`.`id` WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`name`,' ',''),'\)',''),'\(',''),'-','') LIKE '%something%'
```

(REPLACE - replacing of " ", "(", ")", "-" in name column)

1) steelmarks table have about 15 columns - I need to replace

```
`mmetal`.`id`, `mmetal`.`name`, `steelmarks`.`EN`, `steelmarks`.`DIN`,`steelmarks`.`column3`,...,...,...`
```

with something like

```
`mmetal`.`id`, `mmetal`.`name`, `steelmarks`.*
```

but it not works

2) I wish to use LIKE function with **REPLACE** to **all** selected columns **except `id`** columns in both tables, not only "name". Something like:

```
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ALL COLUMNS,' ',''),'\)',''),'\(',''),'-','') LIKE '%something%'
```

now i need to use

```
WHERE REPLACE...column1 LIKE %something% OR REPLACE...column2 LIKE %something% OR REPLACE...column3 LIKE %something% OR ...
```

Do you have any suggestion for my questions, please?

Comment: please provide your table structure and WHAT you want to achieve (verbal).

Comment: I am creating search function and I have extra table (steelmarks) with id and columns with standard names (like EN, DIN, W.Nr,...) for search through. I wish to achieve search query which will be short and which allows me to search in all columns without need too know their columnnames. There is now about 10-15 columns, but can be more in future.

Answer (score 0):

The replace and like operators only operate on one column at a time.  The following might do what you want, but you still have to list all the columns:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(concat_ws('|', col1, col2, col3, . . . ),' ',''),'\)',''),'\(',''),'-','') LIKE '%something%'
```

This concatenates the values together with a separator.

Alternatively, you could query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` with something like:

```
select concat(replace(<YOUR EXPRESSION HERE>, 'col1', c.column_name), ' and')
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name = YOURTABLEHERE
```

Then use the results to construct your query.

Comment: For second question is this great answer for me. Query is now really shorter. Thx